# macOS Sierra on AWS with VM image

Tags: amazon-web-services

Can you run a VM image of sierra on AWS? Since AWS import supports Linux and Unix Kernels.

Answer (score 6):

OSX uses a different kernel base and even though it works on VMWare on windows it'll simply never work on AWS, you can run other Linux unix distros but sierra will simply just never work on aws, it will not boot. Sorry but a bunch of people have tried this and it sucks, but it be insane if it would.

Even though AWS DOES boot VM's with windows and Linux, any distro macOS requires extra features required to boot, AWS simply doesn't have these, they work on your desktop, so your only option would be to run this in your PC.

If you need a cloud base etc, best bet is to get, use a hackintosh.

By the way AWS CAN run the VM but Amazon will never allow it, at least. They purposely block this from their service so people wouldn't use it.

The Hardware that Amazon uses **can run anything**, **even a hackintosh**, but the mac part and the kernel required to run it is blocked from a developer level so it wouldn't function, they allow everything else, Linux and windows.

Sorry.
Cheers.

Comment: What is the source of this information? Are you speculating or do you have direct evidence that this is the case?